# Eclipse RCP hand over home location via vmargs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have build a RCP application containing a placeholder which should point to my eclipse home directory at runtime. The placeholder should be filled during the application startup.

Currently it works if i hand over the path in a very static way in the eclipse.ini file via:

```
-vmargs
-Dproperty=c:/.../my_rcp_application
```

My goal is to achieve a dynamic solution like:

```
-vmargs
-Dplaceholder=${project_loc}
```

Sadly this works just if the application is beeing started from Eclipse (Run As->...).

What i tried so far is a Maven like approach:

```
-vmargs
-Dproperty=./
```

And an approach with Platform URLs:

```
-vmargs
-Dproperty=platform:/base
```

Those approaches were not successfull.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use something similar to this in your code: `Platform.getInstallLocation()`.

There are other possible solutions as well...

Comment: The placeholder which needs to be filled is not in my java code. So this seems for me to be a workaround too. I would have to create a bundle which starts at a very low start-level and publishes the placeholder as system variable. But i thought about such a kind of solution too. Thought there are better possibilities.

Comment: If it have to very early, then use the Location service directly in your code. Or in the activator of the application plug-in...